# javascript const in javascript library

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a small javascript library as shown below. What I really want is when I call

```
console.log(tnd().pv);
```

it should output same number and not generate new number everytime. I know the issue is it calls Math.random everytime I console log. But how can I do so that it outputs same number?

```
(function () {
    var tnd = function() {
        return new tnlib();
    };
    var tnlib = function() {
        this.version = function(){
            console.log('1.0');
        };
        this.pv = Math.random()*10000000000000000;
    };
    if(!window.tnd) {
        window.tnd = tnd;
    }
})();
```

Comment: execute `tnd()` outside of `console.log()` and store it, then access `.pv` from the stored instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't execute `Math.random()` on each invocation of `tnlib`, but as a static variable:

```
(function () {
    function tnd() {
        return new tnlib();
    }
    function tnlib() {
    }
    tnlib.prototype.version = function(){
        console.log('1.0');
    };
    tnlib.prototype.pv = Math.random()*10000000000000000;
    if (!window.tnd) {
        window.tnd = tnd;
    }
}());
```

(or, if you really need to make `pv` an instance property):

```
    var staticPv = Math.random()*10000000000000000;
    function tnlib() {
        this.pv = staticPv;
        …
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up going with the second option.